# How do I fix PHP_Beautifier's empty lines?

Tags: php, php-beautifier

I am currently using [PHP_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/) for formatting code with the following command like options

```
-t -l "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=bsd) NewLines(before=T_CLASS:function:T_COMMENT,after=T_COMMENT)"
```

It works great except for the fact that it strips out all the blank lines. After a bit of searching, I found it posted as a [bug](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=12271) that is open since 2007.

I tried looking into the [codebase](http://beautifyphp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/beautifyphp/trunk/) but was unable to locate the specific code that does this. I appreciate any help I can get in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm clbustos, the developer of PHP_Beautifier. This is one of the most requested features, so I expected to implement it on the next release.
If you want to dig, the function to see if PHP_Beautifier::removeWhitespace

Answer (score 1):

Also needing this beautifier, while preserving blank lines in the sources.

I did check out the last version of this script, and I've done a dirty hack (not being a PHP dvpr...) : commenting two lines in the file `beautifier.php` in the function `public function removeWhitespace()`

```
 for ($i = count($this->aOut) -1 ; $i >= 0 ; $i--) { // go backwards
            $cNow = &$this->aOut[$i];
            if (strlen(trim($cNow)) == 0) { // only space
                if (!$this->addedBlankLine || ($cNow!="\r" && $cNow!="\n")) {
                      //array_pop($this->aOut); // delete it!
                      //$pop++;****
                }
            } else { // we find something!
                $cNow = rtrim($cNow); // rtrim out
                break;
            }
        }
```

This hack does preserve all the blank lines, but there's a side effect : some unwanted lines appears after brackets, and all the tabs characters are not replaced, but it's better for me than not having blank lines...