# Modify PHP_Beautifier in Vim to not strip empty lines

Tags: php, vim, syntax, php-beautifier

Just finished incorporating [PHP_Beautifier](http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/) into Vim and the fact that it removes whitespace irks me. Apparently it's a [bug](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=12271) since 2007. There is a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265564/fixing-php-beautifiers-empty-lines-problem/5459385#5459385) to fix this problem, but it leads to other problems. Instead I decided to use a round about method.

First Convert multiple blank lines to a single blank line via the command  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706076/vim-delete-blank-lines/726158#726158)

```
:g/^\_$\n\_^$/d
```

Next Convert all blank lines to something unique like so (make sure it does not get changed during beautification)

```
:%s/^[\ \t]*\n/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';\r/ge
```

Next Call PHP_Beautifier like so

```
:% ! php_beautifier --filters "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=k&r) NewLines(before=if:switch:foreach:else:T_CLASS,after=T_COMMENT:function)"<CR>
```

Finally Change all unique lines back to empty lines like so

```
:%s/$x='It puts the lotion on the skin';//ge
```

All four work when I tested them independently. I also have the third step mapped to my F8 key like so

```
map <F8> :% ! php_beautifier --filters "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=k&r) NewLines(before=if:switch:foreach:else:T_CLASS,after=T_COMMENT:function)"<CR>
```

But when I try to string the commands together via the pipe symbol, like so (I padded the pipes with whitespace to better show the different commands)

```
map <F8> :g/^\_$\n\_^$/d    |    %s/^[\ \t]*\n/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';\r/ge      |      % ! php_beautifier --filters "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=k&r) NewLines(before=if:switch:foreach:else:T_CLASS,after=T_COMMENT:function)"     |     %s/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';//ge<CR>
```

I get the following error

```
Error detected while processing /home/xxx/.vimrc:
line  105:
E749: empty buffer

E482: Can't create file /tmp/vZ6LPjd/0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How do I bind these multiple commands to a key, in this case F8.

---

Thanks to ib's answer, I finally got this to work. If anyone is having this same problem, just copy this script into your .vimrc file

```
func! ParsePHP()
    :exe 'g/^\_$\n\_^$/d' 
    :%s/^[\ \t]*\n/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';\r/ge
    :exe '%!php_beautifier --filters "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=k&r)"'
    :%s/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';//ge 
endfunc

map <F8> :call ParsePHP()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some Ex commands, including `:global` and `:!`, a bar symbol (`|`) is
interpreted as a part of a command's argument (see `:help :bar` for the full
list).  To chain two commands, the first of which allows a bar symbol in its
arguments, use the `:execute` command.

```
:exe 'g/^\_$\n\_^$/d' |
\   %s/^[\ \t]*\n/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';\r/ge |
\   exe '%!php_beautifier --filters "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=k&r) NewLines(before=if:switch:foreach:else:T_CLASS,after=T_COMMENT:function)"' |
\   %s/$x = 'It puts the lotion on the skin';//ge
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your example (no matching `"` for `"ArrayNested()`), and am having a hard time trying to make it work

Comment: Problem has to do with mapping to the <F8> key. When I copy paste the above code into vim (and add `"`) it works.

Comment: Also, `'g/^\_$\n\_^$/d'` complains if no patterns are found\

Comment: @puk:  I just copied your commands for the matter of illustration of using `:exe` to chain `|`-sensitive commands.  Debugging your original commands is a separate issue.

Comment: @puk:  The `:global` command does not cause any errors if there is no matching lines.  What kind of "complaint" do you get exactly?  Does it occur when you manually run that `:global` command?

Comment: I actually fixed (if you read the modified section of my question). The problem was in the `map <F8>`. It didn't work, so I moved your answer into a function, and instead did `map <F8> :call ParsePHP()<CR>`. Thanks for your help.